# Why is 就 needed in 美國國務院稱華府仍未就卡舒吉案下定論? If it's needed, shouldn't it precede 仍未?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

[This news article](http://news.rthk.hk/rthk/ch/component/k2/1428856-20181118.htm) contains the following title: 美國國務院稱華府仍未就卡舒吉案下定論

1) Why is the 就 needed? If it's needed, shouldn't it precede 仍未?

2) Is 仍 the literary version of 還？ In other words, if you were to speak this instead of write this, you would say, "美國國務院稱華府還未就卡舒吉案下定論"?

Comment: 就:with regard to，concerning，下：reach （final conclusion）, come to （a decision）, 定论：final conclusion; the last word (search site for previous discussions of 就)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For question 1

The word 就 actually bears a lot of meaning, you can check it out [here](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/xs/5C31.htm).

Commonly, we use 就 as **would**, for example,

```
 你   再    吵  ,  你  就    死     定    了.   
You again noisy, you would die for sure.    (Literal translation)
```

But, in formal literature (such as news), 就 is normally treated as a preposition as **with regard to**. To be simple, you can think of 就 as 對 in such situation.

### For question 2

In modern Chinese, adverb comes before preposition.

```
adverb -> preposition
```

Since, 就 is a preposition in such situation, and 仍未 is an adverb. It is normal that 仍未 should come before 就.

P/S: You won't want to use 就 as **with regard to** when speaking, people won't understand it.

Comment: 仍未 is an adverb? in three dictionaries, there were no entries for 仍未, only separate ones for 仍 and 未. thanks for the detailed and helpful answer!

Comment: if 就 acts like 對 here, why do you need 下? wouldn't 下 be redundant?

Comment: see comment #1, sentence skeleton: 美国下定论 (verb 下 to arrive at (a decision, conclusion etc, object: 定论 final conclusion,
accepted argument), **仍未** : not yet，see e.g. **iciba** ,bkrs

Comment: 2 more examples of 双音节 adverbs with 未 as 2nd syllable and similar meaning：  尚未 not yet, still not、从未 never

Comment: re comment #4 (comment #3 following answer) make it "sentence stem （句干），basic sentence model(基干句模): 国务院下定论" （美国 is "国务院" 的 定语)

Answer (score 2):

1. 仍未=仍+未, 仍=still, 未=not. Altogether, 仍未 = not yet. This is a compound word which is not usually collected in dictionaries. Yes, 就 means "with regard to" here, and you could use the single character 对 as an alternative.  Using this alternative, put 对 in front 仍未 seems a bit awkward here.
2. Yes, you could use 还 instead of 仍. But this is a written material, and the author try to make it formal, so 仍 would be better.

For further questions:

下结论 = make conclusions, 下定论 = make definitive conclusions. Here 下 acts like the word "make". It is necessary, otherwise no verbs exist in the sentence.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! so 仍未 is the same as 還沒, except more formal?

Comment: Yeah, just as you thought.